# What information do you need to provide for a domestic wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer

I need to provide details to receive a domestic wire transfer to my US-based bank from another US-based bank. What details do I need to provide?

[This Yahoo! Answers questions](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101222104454AA67NI2) suggests that the following is required:

> Info from the bank that will reicive the funds: Routing # or ABA# (this is the first set of #s on you checks, Account #, name adress and sometimes phone # of the bank receiving funds and name on account it is transfering to. 
>   Also the bank will want the funds you are transfering to be collected I.e. deposited in the account for at least a week. The transfer can sometimes take up to 48 hrs depending on bank procedure.

Spelling errors and banking does not make me feel confident in the answer, and I cannot find a similar question here that provides this information. When providing information to receive a domestic wire transfer, what information do I need to provide?

Comment: Did you ask your bank? They should be able to tell you what they require to receive or send via wire. You should also ask about how long they hold onto the the funds.

Comment: Can I send money to a family at new York without having an account with America bank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on the receiving end, you will not need to provide any information to your bank. Wire transfers are initiated by the sending party.

If you are sending a wire transfer, you will need to provide the following information about the recipient:

1. ABA/Routing number of the receiving bank
2. Name/address/phone number of the receiving bank
3. Recipient's bank account number
4. Recipient's name (as listed on the account)
5. Recipient's address (as listed on the account)

If you need to give this information to a company so they can send you a wire, this is the information you should provide for them. Domestic wire transfers don't require SWIFT/IBAN.

Comment: Thank you Noah! This is exactly what I was looking for. You would think that banks would display this prominently for folks who need it.

Comment: Just thoughts from overseas: With this bunch of information, I understand why wire transfers in the USA are not that common. In Europe, you just need recipient's name, the IBAN and sometimes the SWIFT/BIC. The IBAN contains information such as a routing number. Why address and phone of the receiving bank should be needed, or the recipient's address, is not clear to me.